# Foursquare v2 API - missing venue data

Tags: foursquare

When I manage my venues via web interface, I see a Store ID field.

The field is visible in CSV export as "Manager Note".

But when I fetch venue details via v2 API, the field is not peresent in JSON response.

I tried three endpints: [Venue Detail](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues), [Managed Venues](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/managed) and [Venue Stats](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/stats) - they do not return my Store ID field.

I want to use JSON API, not CSV export.

Is it a bug in v2 API? Or is it by design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an oversight. We'll be adding it to managed venues & venue stats shortly. thanks for bringing it to our attention!

Comment: Thank you. Now, it would be great if I could subscribe to be notified when this problem is fixed... Is there such thing as a Changelog for the Foursquare API?

Comment: We list non-trivial changes to the API in the changelog: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/changelog

Comment: storeIds should start appearing in these responses later today. Thanks for your patience!